# My C program not providing expected output

Tags: c

I am a beginner in programming and I am learning C . I tried to read the contents from a file and do some processing on it .

The following is the program that I had written :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp ;
    int k = 0 ;

    char c ;
    while (c = getc(stdin))
    {
        if (c == 'a')
        { 
            ++k;
        }
    }

    printf ("the value of k is %i" , &k) ;
}
```

And the file had input :

```
 > hkjkjaaaaaaaaaak
 > 
 > hjkjlkaaaaaaaaaghgh
 > 
 > hjhkjklklklklklk
```

But I did not get any output in the console .
    I ran it on another online IDE and I got a run-time error saying "Time limit exceeded"

What can be the reason for the absence of output . 
Is it because  I needed to somehow specify EOF character in the absence of which the program keeps running on and on?

After getting help from the answers I replaced the code with the following :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp ;
    int k = 0 ;

    char c ;
    while (c  = getc(stdin) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == 'a')
        { 
            ++k;
        }
   }


   printf ("the value of k is %i" , k) ;
}
```

This time the program ran and I got an output saying :

```
the value of k is 0.
```

Did it somehow reach EOF from the very beginning ?To verify this I tried comparing the character with 'h' and got the same output .

Is it because getc returns integer and this is not matching with any of the characters in the text ?

Thanks a lot for all the insights . The code worked at the end .Cheers

Comment: `FILE *fp` does not open any file. It simply declares a pointer to a file object

Comment: When does `c  = getc(stdin)`  become false? Need to change this condition to take into account EOF

Comment: There are *multiple* problem with the code you show. To begin with [`getc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getc) return an ***`int`***. This is very important. It also *doesn't* return zero for end-of-input. Then `&k` gives you a *pointer* to `k`. I recommend you *start over* [with a couple of good beginners books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: `getc` returns the read `char` as an `unsigned char` cast to an `int`, or `EOF` on end of file or error, and not `0`. Your loop will never break unless you have a break condition.

Comment: `char c`->`int c`, `while ...` -> `while ((ch = getc(stdin)) != EOF)`

Comment: `c  = getc(stdin) != EOF` (your code) and `(ch = getc(stdin)) != EOF` (the correct suggestion) are not the same, due to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: @UnholySheep : Nice insight .

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler should have warned you about this:

```
while (c = getc(stdin) != EOF)
```

> warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [`-Wparentheses`]

Because `!=` (inequality) has a [higher priority](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) over `=` (assignment), the line is interpreted as

```
while (c = (getc(stdin) != EOF))
           ^                  ^
```

Note the unexpected parentheses, so the value of `c` can only be zero or one, so `c=='a'` would never be true as `'a'` is never equal to 1.

Changing that to

```
while ((c = getc(stdin)) != EOF)
       ^               ^
```

can give you the desired result.

You should consider removing `FILE* fp` because it does nothing at all. It defines a pointer but is never used later, and is likely optimized away by the compiler.